# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Beginning a sentence with 'with'

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositional-phrases

I am unsure about the following sentence:

> With research being an important milestone for the faculty, I hope to increase the output of my publications in the future.

I'm unsure about starting the sentence with 'with'. Is the above grammatically correct?

Comment: Grammatically this sentence is fine. Often the overt subject of a Gerund-Participle clause can be introduced by ***with***. But I am unable to get the meaning of this sentence. It might happen that in context it would make perfect sense.

Comment: I think there's often a difference in nuance between ***With** X being true, [I will do Y]* and ***As/Since** X is true, [I will do Y]*. The first version often implies that X is a ***temporary*** condition (there's the implicit possibility of being ***without X***). On the other hand, the second works better when X is a "timeless, universal" truth. Hence ***With** rents in central London being so high, he had to live in the suburbs*, and ***Since** nothing can travel faster than light, it's unlikely humanity will ever colonise another galaxy*.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct as it is. The initial clause is known as an absolute construction, formed  by the subject of the clause and the verb in "ing".

Absolute constructions can be introduced by "with", and usually express time or reason:

- As research is an important milestone for the faculty, I hope...

Comment: You could also write *Because* instead of *As*.

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically correct, although a somewhat uncommon construction. It's also a little bit hard to read.

A clearer way to write this:

> Because research is important for the faculty, I hope to increase my publishing output.